# Unconnected Fonts for Urdu/Persian/Arabic On Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, fonts, language, facebook

When ever I open Facebook or certain other sites on Firefox Browser , some pages whose native language is Urdu , Arabic or Persian , the fonts displayed are un connected and hence unable to be read.

Kindly help me in this regard.

FireFox Version : Firefox 25.0

Os: Windows 7 Home Premium 64 Bit

P.S : My computer is updated regularly for all kinds of updates.

Comment: The latest version of Firefox as of today is 24. If I use that version to look at Arabic text it seems fine. The "letters" are connected.

Comment: I'm On the Beta Update Channel. The problem only seems on Facebook not on other websites. Don't know the reason!

Comment: If you only see it on Facebook, right-click on the page and select "View Page Source" from the menu. That will show you how they represent the text. It could simply be a font issue.

Comment: Unable to resolve the issue , still ,definately a font issue but unable to ascertain how to solve it.

Comment: Try using another font. In the preferences dialog you can tell firefox to use the fonts *you* specify.